# Unity big scale world simulation performance problem.

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, simulation, frame-rate

We are working on simulation game. We have about 25000 objects at world. All has 1 unity c# script. If we activate empty update function we get 15 fps if we activate empty fixed update with 0.02 time scale we get 1-2 fps at average spec computer. In Will we need to do something on update function. So need some help for this performance problem.

In that case, what can we do for performance?

Thanks for advices and help.

Answer (score 0):

Well even though your question is broad i will try to give some tips. My guess is you are doing some heavy calculations in your Update and this causes fps problems. Also rendering 25000 object at the same time would cause fps issues. First i suggest using [Unity Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and [Unity statistics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingStatistics.html) to find out what is causing the issue. Then my suggestions would be based on the problem i assume:

1. Use Coroutines instead of doing all the calculations in Update.
2. Use [Occlusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) for rendering as minimum objects as possible. You do not need to render objects which are not in [Camera frustum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingFrustum.html).
3. If you have meshes which are detailed use [level of detail](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingFrustum.html) if you have the chance.

If you narrow down your problem i am happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: Using Coroutines instead of the `Update` for doing calculations won't change anything as they also run in the main thread and therefore block the rendering

Comment: Yeah but with coroutines you can return before that calculation is completed. You do not have that chance in `Update`. Therefore, it drops the fps because update can't  be executed in time. Am i missing something?

Comment: What you are describing sounds more like [async-await](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Async/await) actually. For me it is hard to understand what kind of calculation you would wait for in a Coroutine.

Comment: Any calculation which takes time makes sense to me to be used in a coroutine. Generating meshes in run time for example. Is not async-await is the one of the most important reasons why we use coroutines?

Comment: Coroutines still run in the main thread and are not asynchronous. They just allow you to spread instructions out over an amount of time or to wait for other instructions to complete. If you do not have something that just waits or executes something that shall happen "one step each frame" Coroutines are not what you want. It's kind of like having multiple tiny `Update` methods running one iteration(until hitting a `yield`) each frame

Comment: I understand that coroutines are not asynchronous. My point is for example instead of doing 1 million iteration in 1 frame, you can do 1000 iterations or however you want in each frame using coroutines which will decrease delay caused by your scripts.

Comment: Thanks for tips @AliKanat, I have started to learn componenet system but I put empty update functions and meshes are only 2D image. I will try occulision culling. Have a nice days...

Answer (score 0):

The very need to make a call to Update() is one of the major slowdowns in Unity. That's why they are now pusing towards Entity Component System where there is no need for such jumps.
If all the objects are having the same script, it should be quite easy to modify the code so that only 1 object has the script, but operates (i.e. via a for (;;) loop) on all other objects. This should bring massive improvements already.

Aslo if theres any chance your objects share meshes - do use Instanced Mesh Rendering it is faster by two orders of magnitude

Comment: Thanks, I started to learn Unity's new component and Job system.